# Angular&rxjs: autocomplete race condition problem

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this code for returning data from my api:

```
private searchTerm = new Subject<string>();
public termsArray: any = [];

constructor(private apiService: DataService){
                    this.searchTerm
                    .debounceTime(200)
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .subscribe(
                        term => {
                            let data = (this.apiService.getSearchTest(term))
                            if (data) {
                                data.pipe(
                                            takeUntil(this.searchTerm.pipe(skip(1)))
                                        )
                                    .subscribe(response => {
                                    this.termsArray = response.suggestions as Array<any>;
                                    console.log(this.termsArray); //just debug
                                }, err => {
                                    console.log(err);

                                });
                            }

                        });
}

autocompleteTest = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        map(term => term.length < 1 ? []
            : this.termsArray
                .filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                .slice(0, 10))
        )

onKeyUpSearch(searchText: string){
    if (searchText !== "") this.searchTerm.next(searchText);
}
```

So, the `api` calls works fine and converted to array as well.
I attached the typeahed to `autocompleteTest` and it works but with race condition.. after a few research anyone just told you should replace the `map` function in the `autocompleteTest` with `switchMap` for waiting the data.

How should I do that correctly with the `switchMap` to avoid the race condition?

Comment: Where's the race condition? First of all don't subscribe inside another `subscribe`. You can use `concatMap` or in this case even better `switchMap(term => this.apiService.getSearchTest(term))`

Comment: The array is updating well for each call, but the autovomplete grab it just after the the next call. so for example you search for 'a' and you should get an array with 5 'a' eements, then you add 'b' now it's 'ab' the array of the 'a' is updating to the autocomplete

Comment: yeah, that's why you shouldn't subscribe inside another subscribe and rather use an operator such as `switchMap` that automatically unsubscribes from the previous Observable.

Comment: I changed it to:
this.searchTerm
.debounceTime(200)
.distinctUntilChanged()
.switchMap(term => this.apiService.getSearchTest(term))
.subscribe(response => { this.termsArray = response.suggestions as Array<any>;
}, err => {
console.log(err);
});
now it says:
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like that:

```
this.searchTerm.pipe(
    debounceTime(200)
    distinctUntilChanged()
    switchMap(term => {
        let data = (this.apiService.getSearchTest(term));
        if (!data) { return of(null); }
        return data.pipe(
            takeUntil(this.searchTerm.pipe(skip(1)))
        );
    })
).subscribe(response => {
    this.termsArray = (response) ? response.suggestions as Array<any>: []; 
    console.log(this.termsArray); //just debug
}, err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I have added a return `of(null)` because you should always return an observable inside a switchMap operator. Otherwise, you would get:

> TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You
>   can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable